# To what celestial bodies are GRAIL-like missions planned?

Tags: artificial-satellite, gravity, grail, remote-sensing, mapping

[GRAIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRAIL) recently constructed a complete gravity map of Luna's irregular gravity field.

- Are similar GRAIL missions on the anvil to any other Celestial bodies as yet?
- As a corollary (probably opinion-based), should future missions to any body include a similar GRAIL map exercise as a preliminary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an effort to map Earth's gravity, [GRACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment), which has been ongoing since 2002. It's produced this:

[image]

<sup>Neat, right?</sup>

Several GRAIL-like missions are planned / in progress / completed.

- [Mars Express](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Mars_Express/First_Mars_Express_gravity_results_plot_volcanic_history).
- [LISA](http://lisa.nasa.gov/), a probe designed to measure gravitational fields in space, with hopes of finding black holes.
- [Magellan](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet.html) mapped Venus' gravitational anomalies.
- [MESSENGER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER) for Mercury
- [Cassini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens) mapping the gravity fields of Saturn and it's moons.
- [GEORGE](http://works.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1244&context=jeremy_straub), a proposal for a probe to Uranus with one purpose being to '*characterize the gravitational field of Uranus and make a gravity map*'.

As for your other question, I would say that it would certainly be *nice* to have such data on gravity variations, but it's not strictly necessary. We can deal with such things as we come to them with just a few thrusters and make up for what variations in trajectory are caused.

Comment: I should have specified future surface missions to a planet in the latter question. A purely hypothetical scenario for the purpose of illustration - gravimeters are used by some volcanologists to track magma movement; perhaps a grav map of Io may thus prove useful to low orbit/landing craft.